# Search in a table on multiple columns with React, Node.js and Mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux-saga

There is a table with multiple columns and now it is possible to search for a column. When a text is written in the search box, a filter is performed and only the rows containing that word on that column are shown.

For example, there are 3 columns: **name**, **brand**, **sales**. The search is done for column **name**. I want to make it search through all the columns but I don't know how.

Here is how is works now.

React file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Creators } from '../../../actions';
import Layout from '../../../components/Layout/Layout';
import ContentContainer from '../../../components/Layout/ContentContainer';
import GenericTable from '../../../components/Table/GenericTable';
import OneColumn from '../../../components/Layout/OneColumn';
import SearchBox from '../../../components/SearchBox/SearchBox.component';
import TabContainer from '../../../components/Layout/TabContainer';

class Products extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      query: {
        name: '',
        brand: '',
        sales: '',
      },
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { getProducts, getProviders } = this.props;
    getProducts(this.state.query);
    getProviders();
  }

  searchHandler = event => { // here is the search function 
    const { getProducts } = this.props;
    getProducts({
      name: event.target.value, // it works for only for name column now
      brand: this.props.query.brand,
      sales: this.props.query.sales,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const listHeaders = ['ID', 'Name', 'Brand', 'Sales'];

    const listTab = (
      <ContentContainer>
        <div>
          <div>
            <SearchBox
              placeholder="Search product"
              onChange={this.searchHandler} // here is the search box
            />
          </div>
          <GenericTable // the table 
            id="products-table"
            headers={listHeaders}
            rows={listRows}
            entityName="products"
            idList={listIdList}
          />
        </div>
      </ContentContainer>
    );

    return (
      <Layout>
        <OneColumn>
          <TabContainer>
            <Tab.Pane>{listTab}</Tab.Pane>
          </TabContainer>
        </OneColumn>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  products: state.products.products,
  query: state.products.query,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getProducts: Creators.getProductsRequest,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Products);
```

The query is built with redux-saga:

```
const api = API.create();

export function* getProducts({ query }) {
  let urlQuery = '';
  if (query && query.name) {
    urlQuery += `&name=${query.name}`;
  }

  if (query && query.brand) {
    urlQuery += `&brand=${query.brand}`;
  }

  if (query && query.sales) {
    urlQuery += `&price=${query.sales}`;
  }

  try {
    const response = yield call(api.getProducts, urlQuery);
    yield put(Creators.getProductsSuccess(response.data));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(Creators.getProductsFailure(error));
  }
}
```

In Node.js there are 3 methods for the 3 search options, maybe they need to be combined in one but don't know how:

```
findAll: (req, res) => {
    const aggregateOptions = [];
  
       // search by name
       if (req.query.name) {
        aggregateOptions.push({ $match: { name: { $regex: req.query.name, $options: 'i' } } });
      }
  
      // search by brand
      if (req.query.brand) {
        aggregateOptions.push({ $match: { brand: { $regex: req.query.brand, $options: 'i' } } });
      }
  
      // search by sales
      if (req.query.sales) {
        aggregateOptions.push({ $match: { brand: { $regex: req.query.sales, $options: 'i' } } });
      }

    aggregateOptions.push({
      $project: {
        productId: 1,
        name: 1,
        brand: 1,
        sales: 1,
      },
    });

    const myAggregate = Product.aggregate(aggregateOptions);
    Product.aggregatePaginate(myAggregate, options)
      .then(function(results) {
        return res.send(results);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        return res.status(400).send({ message: err.message });
      });
  }
```

So, when I write "s" in the search box, this is the API call: `http://localhost:5000/products&name=s`.

I don't know if it's possible to do something like `http://localhost:5000/products&name=s || brand=s || sales=s` or how can this be made to search from a single search box through all 3 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling getProducts in search Handler you have to call setState and update the state. Concerning what yoh asked I have a solution that require some refactoring, you can set the state to {query: ''} to only filter text and you send it to backend where you perform the searching in the database ( you search for the query filter text in the 1st column then in the 2nd then in the 3rd and push all the results to the same array.

EDITED for redux saga

```
const api = API.create();

export function* getProducts({ query }) {
    let urlQuery = '';
    if(query){
        urlQuery += `&query=${query}`;
    }


    try {
        const response = yield call(api.getProducts, urlQuery);
        yield put(Creators.getProductsSuccess(response.data));
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(Creators.getProductsFailure(error));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I don't get it. Could you be more clear? I mean, "in search Handler you have to call setState and update the state" - how to do that in this case?. I guess you also say to set the state to {query: ""}, so to remove the values from it. and in back-end I don't understand how to do that

Comment: First of all, forget about the setState you can fix it later. When i said set  the state to {query: ""}, I meant removing the name, brand and sales properties. So you have to send only the query string to the backend (nodejs) where you can search for the string in 1st then 2nd then 3rd

Comment: does this affect also redux-saga file? where the query is built

Comment: yeah that why I said you need some refactoring but the changes are quite easy you need to replace the 3 IFs with only one.

Comment: Could you please update your answer with those changes? I don't know how that one IF should look like